# How does the given proof is a spoof? [Completeness is a topological property of metric spaces]

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $f:(X,d)\to (Y,e)$ homeomorphism. So, $f^{-1}$ is continuous. So  $f^{-1}$ is continuous at $y \in Y$, For any $\epsilon \in \mathbb R^+$, $\exists \delta\in \mathbb R^+$:$e(x,y)<\delta \implies d(f^{-1}(x),f^{-1}(y))<\epsilon. $ Let $\{y_n\}$ be a cauchy sequence in $(Y,e)$. For the same $\delta$, There is a $N\in \mathbb N$: $\forall m,n\ge N\implies e(y_n,y_m)<\delta$. Define a sequence $\{x_n=f^{-1}(y_n)\}$.  $\forall m,n\ge N \implies d(f^{-1}(y_n),f^{-1}(y_m))<\epsilon.$ Hence $\{x_n\}$ converges in $(X,d)$. So $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$. Since $f$ is continuous. Hence $\{y_n\}$ converges to $f(x)$.  How do my argument go wrong?

Comment: Given $\epsilon$, the $\delta$ that you introduced will, in general, depend on $y$. Your argument needs the same $\delta$ to work for infinitely many  $y_n$'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your argument, you are using the uniform continuity criteria. In general, given $\epsilon \gt 0$, same  $\delta  $  will not work for every point.